# Php: echo vs include html file

Tags: php, include, echo

In a php script:
-What is the difference between

```
echo "<p>info</p>"
```

and simply writting html content (what include "htmlfile" basically does)?

```
include "file.html"
```

Observation:
I read that echo sends a command to web server to send http response, while including a html file waits till the processing php code is done.

In the latter case, does the php module "echoes" at the end of the processing all the html that was written in the php file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I realised:

1. A php engine does the following:

-takes the php file

-if it encounters html tags (outside any php tag), it sends to output buffer

-if it encounters php tags, it execute php code inside.

2. Include file.html statement does the same thing as above, with the observation that all code is analysed sequentially, from top to bottom. 
   From here it comes the misunderstanding that include statements actually copy paste code. No. It involves a mechanism of analysing and/or executing.
3. Echo sends directly to output buffer
4. You can't have html tags directly inside php tags.

I hope this can be helping for you in case you have wonders like mine.